# Does the Widowmaker reward metal when the sentry is actively shooting?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

Recently, I received the Widowmaker, and thought that initially it was a very useless weapon.  It required metal to shoot, and did the same damage as a normal shotgun.

However, on one server I played on, something weird occurred.

My setup was: Widowmaker – Pistol – Gunslinger

I set up my mini-sentry, and when I switched to my Widowmaker, the minisentry targeted an enemy and began to shoot him. And I immediately began to receive metal.  I received metal until around 412 metal (which was odd, because the cap was 200) and then my mini-sentry was destroyed.

I tried the exact same scenario on a different server, and it didn’t work.  So since I tried both, I’m extremely confused whether or not having a sentry shooting at an enemy while in the primary slot (Widowmaker) grants you metal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it does not. The Widowmaker only awards metal for damage that it does.

The server that you were playing on must have been running a special plugin.

[Source](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Widowmaker)

Comment: You should probably also add that server you were on to your blacklist so you never see it again.

Comment: It's a great server though, so I'll probably keep it.  Plus, on the server, it's a viable strategy.